# Using Swift to send commands to Raspberry Pi through ssh

Tags: xcode, swift, ssh, raspberry-pi

I'm running OSMC on my pi, and at night I like to turn off the HDMI at night without turning off the whole pi. Right now I'm doing that either through terminal or through a little Automator workflow I created. Recently I've wanted to incorporate that into a status bar application. The problem I'm having is figuring out how to ssh into my pi using swift, and then, once I've ssh'd into it, sending commands to the pi. Here's what I have right now, which isn't working:

```
@IBAction func OSMCClicked(sender: NSMenuItem) {
    let task = NSTask()
    task.launchPath = "/usr/bin/"
    if (sender.state == NSOnState) {
        sender.state = NSOffState
        task.arguments = ["mosh osmc@172.19.32.246", "osmc stop", "exit"]
        //task.arguments = ["mosh osmc@172.19.32.246"]
        //task.arguments = ["OSMC stop"]
        //task.arguments = ["exit"]
    }
    else {
        sender.state = NSOnState
        task.arguments = ["mosh osmc@172.19.32.246", "osmc start", "exit"]
        //task.arguments = ["mosh osmc@172.19.32.246"]
        //task.arguments = ["osmc start"]
        //task.arguments = ["exit"]
    }
    task.launch()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So I just didn't know that much about ssh or NSTask. Turns out the launch path can be `/usr/bin/ssh`, and the arguments would then be `["osmc@172.19.32.246", "osmc start", "exit"]`. Except that the `osmc` alias is in my .bashrc file, which doesn't work when it's not interactive, so I just ended up substituting that for the actual commands, and using the -t flag instead of exit.

Comment: But how would you insert the password?

Comment: Follow the instructions on this page http://steve.dynedge.co.uk/2012/05/30/logging-into-a-rasberry-pi-using-publicprivate-keys/